# Android heavy asyncTask causes phone to reboot

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Here is what I want to implement:

When the user clicks a button, I start about 4 to 5 `AsyncTask`s; each `AsyncTask` starts a URL request, parses the XML returned by the URL request and finally returns the array with the parsed objects. And before all the `AsyncTask` finish, I show a rotating arrow in the middle of the screen.

The problem is that sometimes the phone suddenly reboots when the searching started a few seconds and I don't know why. This does not appear very often, but it's very annoying.

Also, the rotating animation of the arrow is not smooth: sometimes when the parser is working, the animation will delay for a few seconds.

I'm thinking about if this is a memory problem? Or if I should do the parsing work in a serial order?

Any ideas are welcome, thanks!

========================================

*Note:*

The code is too long so I can't paste it here. There are 5 parsers and too many logic.

Also, when the phone reboots randomly during the search, there is no error log

Comment: could you post your code ?

Comment: A system reboot indicates a serious problem with either the hardware or some system software. Can you test with other devices? I guess, there is not much you can do about it. If you by chance find out which circumstances trigger the reboot you can try to avoid them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Java threads instant of asyncTask :

- Network operations which involve moderate to large amounts of data
  (either uploading or downloading) High-CPU tasks which need to be run
  in the background
- Any task where you want to control the CPU usage
  relative to the GUI thread

And there are lot of good resources over internet which may help you:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html http://www.mergeconflict.net/2012/05/java-threads-vs-android-asynctask-which.html